# How do I create a button to sort a table by certain attributes? Im using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, html-table

I created this table for a To-Do list app for projects. I want to create buttons that will sort the table by table, client, what's done, and whats not. I'm not sure how to go about it..

Here is the code for the table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="headers">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>Done</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody class="col-md-2" id="listItems">
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
      <tr id="table">
        <td><%= project.title %></td>
        <td><%= project.client %></td>
        <td><%= project.description %></td>
        <td><%= project.hours %></td>
        <td><%= project.done %></td>

        <td><%= link_to " #{image_tag('show.png')}".html_safe, project, id:'showButton' %></td>


        <td><%= link_to " #{image_tag('edit.png')}".html_safe, edit_project_path(project),     id:'editButton' %></td>

        <td><%= link_to " #{image_tag('destroy.png')}".html_safe, project, id:'destroyButton', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I hear datatables (jquery plugin) can do such things.

Comment: You can do it using the plugin that Sergio suggests, or you can do it from within Rails (by making an additional request to your controller every time a table header is clicked). Do you have a preference?

Comment: @JackZelig I would like to do it within Rails, I'd like to have a 4 buttons: Sort by Client A-Z, Sort by Client Z-A, Sort by Done-Not Done, then Most Recent (the normal list). If that is possible! Thank you

Comment: I suggest using jquery instead of rails/ruby.  On smaller sets it would be way faster to not go to the DB for the sort. If you use the DB (Jack's answer is great), consider putting an index on the field you're sorting on. Just to speed reading up. (I said consider not do)

Comment: @baash05 thanks, I would but I don't really know how to do that. Its for a class project and we've only learned Ruby.

Comment: what happened when you googled for "rails sortable columns" ?

Comment: @TarynEast got a tutorial but can't get it to work

Comment: Well, how about you ask a new question that tells us all about the tutorial, the code you've tried and what the error is... :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a great RailsCast explaining how to do this: [#228 Sortable Table Columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns)

However, as answers simply linking to a solution are frowned upon, here's how you would implement this in your case (code borrowed heavily from RailsCast episode):

First, create a helper method. It should take two arguments. The first argument is the column name and the second is the column header text if this is different from the column name. The second argument is optional.

```
/app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
  end
end
```

Alter your index.html.erb like so:

```
/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
<tr id="headers">
  <th>Title</th>
  <th><%= sortable "client" %></th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Hours</th>
  <th>Done</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
```

Here, I'm just implementing it on the client column.

In the index action of the projects controller, you do:

```
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
def index
  @projects = Project.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
end

private
def sort_column
  Project.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "client"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ?  params[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

The use of `helper_method` makes the two `sort_` methods available to the ApplicationHelper so that they can be used in the sortable helper.

The two `sort_` methods protect against SQL injection and are used to set sensible default values.

And that's it. Your clients column is now sortable.

Comment: I put all of this code in and I got back an error saying "SyntaxError in ProjectsController#index, Unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end"

Comment: Then you're missing an 'end' or some such.